# c library gl must be installed

Tags: libraries

I am trying to install dangerdeep.  after installing dependancies suggested by web site and scon debug I get the message c library gl must be installed.  I am working with ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you tried already... For me it seems like this would solve your problem:

```
sudo apt-get install libopengl-dev
```

Comment: unable to locate package libopengl or -dev thanks for trying.

Comment: Still it most likely are some missing libs or broken depencies. Whats about "libqt4-opengl-dev" ? 
Just realized libopengl-dev really does not exists in the repos

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and successfully installed `dangerdeep`.

I found that if you open `~/dangerdeep/SConstruct` with sudo privileges and 
edit line 263 to only search for `libGL.so` in the folders `/usr/X11R6/lib/`, `/usr/lib/` and `/usr/local/lib/`, itsolves my problem.

In Ubuntu 14.04 you can find it in `/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/`

and add the folder to the 263 line, using:

```
gllibdirs = ['/usr/X11R6/lib/', '/usr/lib/', '/usr/local/lib/', '/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/']
```

then try install it again!